# How to change the default window size in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon

For some applications cinnamon seems to remember which size they were in last time, so when I start them, the window size is perfect. For others (for example system settings, terminal) this does not seem to be the case. Is there a way to assign a default window size to specific programs, or in general for all programs?

Cheers!

Comment: Use [devilspie](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [Devilspie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6MGy.png):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

> Devilspie is a non-gui utility that lets you make applications start in
> specified workplaces, in specified sizes and placements, minimized or
> maximized and much more based on simple config files.

Create a Devilspie configuration directory for the current user and then create a configuration file for devilspie, for example for gnome-terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.devilspie && echo gedit ~/.devilspie/gnome-terminal.ds
```

Add a desired contents, for example:

```
(if (is (application_name) "Terminal")
     (begin
         (geometry "800x400")
         (center)
     )
)
```

Now the command

```
devilspie
```

will execute the script and all open Terminal windows will be resized and positioned as in the script.

If you want these settings to be there by default, just add the "devilspie" command into your Startup Applications (search for Startup Applications in the Cinnamon main menu):
[image]